# NTC physical simulation

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, heat, thermistor

I have a heating device that uses an external 47 kΩ NTC thermistor as the temperature feedback for temperature control.

What I would like to do is to make the NTC thermistor "wireless", so I could place the NTC sensor far away from the heater, without needing to connect a long two-wire cable.

My initial approach for this (leaving aside the wireless communication and other system management) is to use two separate devices:

1. A transmitter with the physical NTC connected. Transfers calculated resistance to the receiver.
2. Receiver with digital potentiometer(s). Receives the wireless info with resistance and sets it on the digital potentiometer that is connected to the heater.

The issue I see with this setup is that digital pots have very low accuracy (about 8%). I thought it could be compensated with an ADC input on the receiver side, but realized that I will have no GND connection to the heater, and I don't know what voltage it applies to the NTC thermistor. I feel there is a better way to simulate an NTC.

What is the preferred (or state of the art) way of realizing such a design?

Comment: Do you really need it to be analog or is it good enough to tell the heater "hot enough" / "not hot enough"?

Comment: I don't know anythong about the heater interface, thus, need to simulate its physical connection.

Comment: Given your constraints, the most robust and straightforward solution would be if the receiver could use a stepper motor to turn an actual potentiometer. This way the receiver will be completely independent and isolated from the heater circuitry. NOTE: there is no need for an actual NTC thermistor at the transmitter. You can use any type of temperature sensor and just calculate the thermistor resistance using code or a lookup table. NOTE ALSO that the NTC close to the heater may have some safety function. By moving it far away you may cause the heater to be unaware of a localized over-temp.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło yeah but can you just simulate way too hot / way too cold? so you just trick the heater into thinking it's way too cold when you want it to turn on, and way too hot when you want it to turn off?